# Apache Reverse Proxy: (Keeping Existing route alive)

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, http-proxy

I have an app running on **localhost:3000**. I also have another app that is configured to run on virtualhost **local.testserver.com**

I want to create an apache reverse proxy that will route all request from **local.testserver.com/finance** to my app that runs at **localhost:3000**. 
At the same time, I want to be able to access my app when I go to **localhost:3000**.

Below is the configuration I am using currently. This works for routing request from **local.testserver.com/finance** to my **localhost:3000** app. But whenever I visit **localhost:3000** directly it redirects me back to **local.testserver.com**

```
<Location /finance >
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the path on the ProxyPassReverse setting to "/finance" so it knows where to reverse requests back.

You may not need the `<Location /finance>...</Location>` part

```
ProxyPass "/finance" http://localhost:3000
ProxyPassReverse "/finance" "http://localhost:3000"
```

Please refer to the documentation to better understand how 
ProxyPassReverse works here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse